# How to limit the "add new record" behaviour to only one field in a MS Access continuous form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Not sure if this is possible.

I have an MS Access form with a "Continous Form" subform displaying roughly 10 fields 
(Combo boxes, Text Boxes and Check Boxes).

*Allow Additions* is set to Yes.
*Record Selectors* is set to No.

Currently the behaviour of the form is that to add a new row the user can just update any of the available fields.
Is it possible to **limit this "add new record" behaviour to only happen with one specified field** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something such as the code below:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.ControlNameHere.Enabled = False
    Else
        'Do you mean that once a record has been added, the
        'user can update any field? If not, why not just disable 
        'fields that are protected? Otherwise
         Me.ControlNameHere.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. This works like a charm! I actually use this now:  _If Me.NewRecord Then Me.ControlNameHere.Enabled = False  else Me.ControlNameHere.Enabled = True end if_                and this for all fields I want locked/disabled until the record is really added